# Group homology Künneth Formula

Tags: group-theory, homological-algebra, group-cohomology

I am trying to understand Weibel's proof of Künneth Formula for group homology (Prop. 6.1.13 from *An Introduction to Homological Algebra*), and I am struggling with following statement:

Let $G,H$ be groups. Let $P\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ and $Q\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ be free resolutions of $\mathbb{Z}$ respectively over $\mathbb{Z}G$ and $\mathbb{Z}H$. Then, **by the Kunneth Formula for chain complexes**, we get that the homology of $P\otimes_\mathbb{Z}Q$ (seen as total complex of tensor product double complex) is $0$ for non-zero degree.

How one can derive this statement from Künneth Formula for chain complexes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have, by Künneth formula,

$$H_n(P_{\cdot} \otimes_{\Bbb Z} Q_{\cdot}) \cong 
\left(
\bigoplus_{p+q=n} H_p(P_{\cdot}) \otimes_{\Bbb Z} H_q(Q_{\cdot})
\right) \oplus 
\bigoplus_{p+q=n-1} \mathrm{Tor}_1^{\Bbb Z}(H_p(P_{\cdot}), H_q(Q_{\cdot}))$$
When $r>0$, we know that $H_r(P_{\cdot}) = H_r(Q_{\cdot}) = 0$, since these complexes are free resolutions.

When $n>0$ and $p+q=n$, we must have $p>0$ or $q>0$, thus the first direct summand is $0$.

When $n>1$ and $p+q=n-1$, we must have $p>0$ or $q>0$, thus the second direct summand is $0$. If $n=1$, we are left with 
$\mathrm{Tor}_1^{\Bbb Z}(P_0, Q_0) = 0$, since both modules are free over $\Bbb Z[G]$, hence over $\Bbb Z$ (hence flat over $\Bbb Z$). In all cases, when $n>0$, the second direct summand also vanishes.

In other words, we've got : $H_n(P_{\cdot} \otimes_{\Bbb Z} Q_{\cdot}) = 0$ when $n>0$.

Comment: So this is my problem - why higher homology of free resolution are 0? If I was attempting the proof, I would say that exactness changes between $P.$ and augmented complex only at 0th place, so higher homology vanish. But then it would also work for projective resolutions. Is that right?

Comment: If the SES in Kunneth Formula didn't split, the statement would remain true ;)

Comment: @IgorSikora : because a resolution is an exact sequence, so that homology vanishes. Thus I think this specific part doesn't need the complex to have _free_ $\Bbb ZG$-modules as components. However, I needed freeness (flatness) for the vanishing of Tor ; also freeness is used in the sequel of proof 6.1.13.

Comment: Of course, now  I see. Thanks!